# Rendering cloning | item fields are not as per their template

Tags: sxa, templates, item-clones, inheritance

**Environment**: Sitecore 9.0.2 + SXA 1.7.1

**What I am doing**:
The field labels of the inbuilt templates and renderings provided by SXA were not compatible with my requirement. So, I started with creating a rendering variant as mentioned in the [documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/copy-and-customize-a-rendering.html).

So, I cloned the default rendering 'Promo' to 'Promo1'. I noticed that a template 'Prommo1' has also been created.

I modified the fields and their labels of the template 'Promo1'. Further, I created an item 'Item1' based on the template 'Promo1'.

**What I found**:
'Item1' was having the fields and the lables as per the template 'Promo' but I was expecting it to  have the  fields and the  labels as per the template 'Promo1'.

I checked the template by clicking on the link in the 'Quick Info' section of the 'Item1'. And the template  has my changes.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What is the template of "Item1"? Is it Promo or Promo1?

Comment: @PeterProcházka The template is Promo1. The fields and labels in the item are of Promo.

Comment: Navigate to each field and change Title field there. Will create precise answer in a moment

Comment: @PeterProcházka If I  open the template from 'Quick Info' section of the component, I find my changes in the template 'Promo1'. So, where to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to navigate to your new template "Promo1" and for each template field change `Title` field to your desired value like depicted below:

[image]

I am using Promo as example here so change path to your cloned template.